# Does iOS (iPad) close your tabs when off when private browsing is enabled?

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I'm just curious to know if any iOS device (particularly, in this case, the iPad 2) closes the open tabs when I run out of battery ?

Comment: Are you asking if the open tabs will reappear the next time you power your device back on?

Comment: Why not just trying it out yourself and report back with an answer? My guess would be that they remain as they were before the shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

No. Next time when you open safari again, it will reload those sites again. Basically it just remembers all the tabs which you have opened and loads it the next time.